# Screensaver starting before scheduled time

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I am using Windows 7 Professional. I have the screensaver time property set to 8 minutes, but the screensaver starts after only 1 minute of inactivity.

I've tried increasing/decreasing the time but with no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be in your registry. Open up "regedit" and go to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

Once in the Desktop Registry folder (not in any of the sub folders) look for the value:

> ScreenSaverTimeOut

The value is based on time in seconds. So for 8 mins it should be 480

If it's not, set the correct value and see if that makes a difference. After you fix it I suggest cleaning the registry with a tool like [Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) or [Glary](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/glary-utilities/download/)

Furthermore, if you are on a laptop be sure to check your power settings to make sure they're not conflicting with the screen saver.

Comment: Hi Mr. X, Thanks for your support. It worked. :)

Comment: Glad I could help out!